# Has anyone figured out yet how to prevent Chrome from stripping line breaks while saving files, or at least load output into Excel

Tags: excel, jsp, google-chrome, csv

Looks like the problem has persisted since 2012 based on users' agony.

I'm trying to spool CSV data into client Chrome browsers, which turn it into one long line, stripping all LF and CR characters. 
Tried all combos: \n, \r\n, \\n - strips consistently regardless of content-type or content-disposition.

So it's more of a two-part question:

a) does anyone know how to prevent/trick Chrome browsers from doing this?

b) is there a way to break the record in CSV without using the ASCII(10) character

I'm streaming data from the application web server to clients. All browsers are fine saving CSV or loading the doc straight into Excel, except Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that finally worked was the generation of a chr(10)-delimited CSV file on the server and execution of the following JS expression upon pressing the "export" button:

```
location.href="http://$server_name/$CSV_name";
```

In such case, records rendered correctly and were loaded in Excel as expected. Any attempts to generate an inline or an attached document via manipulation of server headers or document types/extensions ended in '\n' (or '\r\n') stripping in Chrome, as opposed to other browsers.

Hope this helps.